# regular expression to replace ^M with \n or to remove ^M

Tags: regex, eclipse, shell, replace, regex-lookarounds

I have a file where I want to remove ^M character from below

line1;^Mline2;

to have output as below:

line1;
line2;

How can I achieve this without creating a temporary file? Would appreciate any shell command, perl command or eclipse find and replace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if by `^M` you mean the literal string `^M` or the control-character (carriage-return). If you mean the literal string:

```
sed -e 's/\^M/\n/g' file
```

If you mean carriage-return:

```
sed -e 's/\r/\n/g' file
```

Comment: actually I had introduced that ^M using \r in eclipse. So I just used the second option and it worked. I had tried using ^M in eclipse. Should have tried to replace \r instead of ^M. Thanks.

Comment: In Eclipse `\R` can be used as platform independent line delimiter in both, in regular expressions and in the _Replace with_ when using regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks @howlger Will explore that option as well.